# Getting model instance by passing field name and not primary ID

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I want to get a model instance using URL as  http://127.0.0.1:8000/db/User/email (i.e. using email as a query) and not by http://127.0.0.1:8000/db/User/1/. How to approach this.

Model:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

serializers.py

```
class EmployeeSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    field = NestedSerializers()

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        #overwrite this method for writable nested serializers.
```

view.py:

```
class UserView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Employee.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EmployeeSerializers
```

urls.py:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('User', views.UserView)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('/', include(router.urls))
]
```

Is it possible to do using ModelViewSet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you are using DRF viewset. If you only ever want to use the email and not the id then you can override the the retrieve function of the viewset like so:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

class UserView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Employee.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EmployeeSerializers        

    def retrieve(self, request):
        employee = get_object_or_404(
                      self.queryset,
                      email=self.kwargs['email']
        )
        serializer = self.serializer_class(employee)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

urls

```
    router = routers.DefaultRouter()
    router.register('^User/(?P<email>.+)/$', views.UserView)

    urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.index, name='index'),
        path('/', include(router.urls))
    ]
```

retrieve is functionality already provided in the viewset class

Comment: What if I wanted to include email as a query?

Comment: this will work for http://127.0.0.1:8000/db/User/email 
give it a shot!

Comment: I am using URL as  127.0.0.1:8000/db/User/xyz@abc.com. It does not match URLconf do I need to change URL patterns.

Comment: ah yes sorry wrote too fast. you will need to pass the email as a parameter which is a change to the url conf. let me update my answer shortly!

Comment: also I realize you are using a capital U in your URLconf, should consider updating to a lowercase u

Comment: Was having a hard time matching URLconfs with 127.0.0.1:8000/db/User/email. Finally fixed it by using lookup _field = "email" in view.py.